# Visual Studio 2012 Acting Weird

Tags: windows, windows-8, updates, uninstall, visual-studio-2012

**I fixed the issued by reinstalling Windows.

A fresh install was not needed.

But I had to use the "Keep personal files only" option.

The "Keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps" option did not help.**

**As a side note, I want clarify that VS12 does not have an Uninstall context menu item in the Control Panel\Programs. It only has "Change" which should normally bring up a menu listing "Repair, Modify, Uninstall".**

[image]

> So I installed Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 x64, but it is acting very weird when I try to uninstall it.
>
> When I click on the only available option "Change", only a brief flash of the VS2012 logo flashes and then nothing.
>
> [image]
>
> I cannot install the Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 either. It does the same "flash" even with the "/layout" command from the command prompt.
>
> **I have spent over an hour trying to figure this out. I am at a loss here.**
>
> Edit: Cannot reinstall either. Even with the direct ISO from Microsoft, the same "flash" occurs and then nothing. Also I did a full Malewarebytes scan and nothing came up.
>
> Edit 2: Safe Mode did not help at all. *Doing a Maleware scan in safe mode, just for the heck of it.* **Nothing found.**
>
> Edit 3: I cannot install/uninstall/update **anything** related to Visual Studio 2012. Not the ISO, Web Download, or Web Install. Nor any version type or platform type. Not even Windows Update will work. Nada, zip, nothing.
> ***I was able to install Visual Studio 2010 again.***

Comment: ask this in the Microsoft MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup

Comment: Ok I just [posted this on the forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/6f024c1f-7df2-4fdb-b055-cc66c0b3bdf0). Thanks for the tip. At this point a full reinstall of Windows 8 might just be easier /sacrasm.

Comment: Turns out my sarcasm bit in the butt. I had to do a reinstall, but at least it wasn't a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any non-ASCII characters in your Windows user name?

Can you try installing the Visual Studio under another user (create a temporary account if you don't have another one - VS should work for all users then)?

Comment: I don't have any non-ASCII characters in my user name "Anonymous".

Comment: Could not install/uninstall/update VS12 on a different user. Same thing as before, quick flash and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the msi for Visual Studio 2012 (or look up the product code) you can try uninstalling it from the command line with:

```
msiexec /uninstall [location of msi/product code] /quiet
```

Full msiexec tutorial from Microsoft here:
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx)

Find your product code like this:

> open system registry and search for
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
>   key (if it's a 32-bit installer on a 64-bit machine, it might be under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID instead). the
>   GUIDs listed under that key are the products installed on this machine
>   find the one you're talking about - just step one by one until you see
>   its name on the right pane This GUID you stopped on is the
>   ProductCode.

Comment: Found "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012" in the 64bit reg key you listed. The app ID was 179CAEE3-011C-424A-9A43-011AB589A7CC but when I ran msiexec.exe it gave me this: "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Comment: I also tried it with the key name which was EB1425FE-3641-47AB-9484-32B62FC8B0B0 but got the same error.

Comment: BTW I am using "..\Windows\System 32\msiexec.exe"

Comment: The full command would be "msiexe /uninstall {179CAEE3-011C-424A-9A43-011AB589A7CC}" You need to add the braces. You can add additional switches at the end to attempt to make it work. Try /quiet or /passive at the end and see what works for you. At the very least try to get the error message.

Comment: I found a program called [msiinv.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239264/anyone-got-a-copy-of-msiinv-exe) in which it lists all the MSI packages. So I am going through and doing "msiexec /x *path*" on anything with the name "Visual Studio 2012" in it. **Although it hasn't had any affect on not being able to run the VS12 installer and reinstalling it.**

Comment: be sure you're uninstalling and then doing a reboot afterwards

Comment: Well I uninstalled everything that came up with "Visual Studio 2012" and "Visual Studio 2010" and rebooted... and all it acomplished was making VS12 unusable. I still cannot install anything related to VS12. I was able to install VS10, however.